# Css Issue with horizontal box layout using -webkit

Tags: css, webkit

The code : http://jsfiddle.net/YM5Cb/
Please take look at the fiddle.
I am trying out webkit models. I was experimenting with horizontal box layout.
See the top right panel, its height is more than its parent.
How to make its height same height as its parent

The above demo works only in chrome and safari. I am learning to create HTML 5 apps for android and ios device. Thats why i am using webkit. So its enough for the code to work on chrome and safari, so it will work fine in ios and android devices

Comment: since its webkit. It works only in chrome and safari.
I am trying to learn making apps for ios and android. So its enough if the code works in webkit browsers

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can try to set the property `height:auto` for child boxes/divs